# Checking if a number is even with only using +, - and recursion

Tags: java, c#, c, recursion

There has to be a way to check if a number is even or odd using recursion, addition and substraction, but without using loops.

I could only get that far (but I am still using `%`):
`boolean odd = (k % 2 == 1);`

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks :)

Comment: Subtract one, if the result is odd then the previous value vas even. Call recursively.

Comment: Please be more judicious with your tags. The fact that you have three languages tagged is always a warning sign that your question is overly broad. And this question doesn't seem to have anything to do with oop at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsEven(int num)
{
    if (num == 1) return false;
    if (num == 0) return true;
    return IsEven(num - 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeatedly subtract 2 (recursion)

Base cases: 0 returns true (even), 1 returns false (odd)

Comment: What if the number is negative?

Comment: Take the absolute value and use the original algorithm.

Comment: And how do you propose to take the absolute value using only addition and subtraction?

Comment: if x<0, x = 0-x

Comment: That's using the less than operator.  That's not in the list of operators you can use.

Comment: @Servy if the number is negativ then you just have to wait a lot longer until it overflows, gets its positiv max value and continue until it reaches 0 or 1. Or maybe it depends how the number you are using handles overflows.

Comment: We've already posited equality, which is also not specified in the original posting.  I don't think that "less than" is an unreasonbale stretch.

Comment: @911DidBush If in a checked context that would throw.  If it's not, then this code produces the wrong value (int.min and int.max are both even, so when you subtract two from an even number you get an odd number accounting for overflow, meaning all negative numbers give the opposite result).

Comment: @Prune If we're just adding operators not specified because it's reasonable to do so then why not just use `%` and be done with it then.

Comment: @Servy Just tested it, at least with java Integer it should also work with negativ numbers as `Integer.MIN_VALUE -1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE` (MIN_VALUE is even (-2^31), MAX_VALUE is odd (2^31-1))

Comment: @911DidBush in C signed integers (unlike unsigned) are not guaranteed to wrap.

Comment: @Servy (1) because **%** is already proscribed; (2) a comparison operator is already included; (3) from the given examples, I guessed that comparisons are allowed, but other arithmetic operators are proscribed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in C for example like this:

```
bool isOdd(int num)
{
    if (num==2) return false;
    else if(num==1) return true;
    else return isOdd(num-2);
}
```

Note that this program only works for numbers greater than 0. How to do it for all numbers is left as an excercise for you :)

Comment: You should check for `num == 2` at first.

Comment: True, just messed up the terms even and odd :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check lowest bit is set

```
  IsOdd = (k & 1) != 0;
```

Comment: I believe `&` wouldn't be allowed. OP said to use `+` and `-` only.

Comment: That's not recursion, and & is not allowed, since only `+` and `-` is.

Comment: For something so trivial why would you ever use recursion - a loop would suffice & be much more efficient. But even a loop is unnecessary.

Comment: I agree a loop would be more efficient but as I want to practice programming I wanted to examine all different approaches to solving that problem

Comment: @PaulF The question is not about optimal solution, it's about solving the problem with certain constraints. Obviously your approach would be right otherwise.

Comment: If allowed, `IsOdd = k & 1;` would be simpler.

Comment: I don't think you would benefit much by practicing recursion on a problem like this.

Comment: @WeatherVane: if the language allows it - I picked this question up via the C# tag - so in my case it is not allowed, but C/C++ you are right

Comment: @PaulF yes, but I did mean if the problem allows it (I forgot there were tags other than C ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following solution:

```
int isEven(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;  // zero is even, return true
    return isOdd(n - 1);
}

int isOdd(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1; // one is odd, return true
    else return isEven(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError` for me. The control flow is confusing. Better to have `isEven(int)` call itself with `n - 2`, and have `isOdd` implemented as `return !isEven(n);`